# Azure Web Job Processing

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I am creating a on demand web job which launches an executable in a directory off my FTP tree, but I can't find the directory on the `cd` command or the executable since the `cd` failed.

My batch file looks like this:

```
cd exedir\w32
file.exe
```

Note: I am FTPing all the files up there for this application, so Visual Studio is not involved.

How can I set up this batch file so it runs correctly?

Answer (score 0):

cd %WEBROOT_PATH% got me to the wwwroot directory and from there it was just a matter of ..\;.\ ok now I know where I am good to go.